# Transform Data („Cost“) in Google Data Studio from „Text“ to „Number“ does not work

Tags: google-sheets, etl, looker-studio, data-transform

**Situation:**

I am about to create a Report in Google Data Studio based on Data copied from someone else into a Google Sheet.

This data includes the metric „cost“ („Gesamtkosten“). GDS identifies this as as text/string.

I want to transform it in GDS into number / currency to use it as a metric.

So far - so simple.

**Already tried:**

1.) Change Type of Data from „Text“ to „Currency“ / „Number“

2.) Changed Type of Data with CAST

`CAST (Rechnungsbetrag Netto (Text) AS NUMBER)`

3.) Replaced „€“ and „.“ and deleted Blancs with REPLACE and TRIM to minimize data on digits.

`TRIM( REPLACE (REPLACE(   Gesamtbetrag, ".",""), "€",""))`

**Data**

Here is a Copy of the Google Sheet with the related Colume:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b3L6p-tdiZRicQIlOHHr3iSLQTCbY7N1Nb1tcBCZv0I/edit

Thanx for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in cell `D2`:

`=arrayformula( iferror( value( regexreplace(trim(C2:C); "[^-\d,]"; "") / sign(len(C2:C)) ) ) )`

Format the result column as **Format > Number > Currency**.

Comment: Hey Doubleunary,

Thank you for your help. This helped.

I solved it in sheets and I will try to adapt the function in GDS.

Great!

Comment: You do not need to adapt the function to GDS. If your data is number in Google Sheets, it should be identified as a number in GDS.